# Simple C++ console I/O issue

Tags: c++, input, output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int Max=20;

struct bop
{
    char fullname[Max];
    char title[Max];
    char bopname[Max];
    int preference;
};

int main()
{
    bop a[5]=
    {
        {"Steve Jobs", "BFF", "Rita",0},
        {"Bill Gates", "BFF2", "Ann",1},
        {"Mark", "BFF3", "Boss", 2},
        {"Edward", "BFF4", "Jiezha", 2},
        {"Larry Page", "BFF5", "Michele", 1}
    };
    cout << "Benevolent Order of Programmers Report\n";
    cout << "a. display by name         b. display by title\n"
            "c. display by bopname      d. display by preference\n"
            "q. quit\n"
            "Enter your choice: ";
    char ch;
    (cin >> ch).get();
    int i;
    while (ch!='q')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'a': for (i=0; i<Max; i++) cout << a[i].fullname << endl; break;
            case 'b': for (i=0; i<Max; i++) cout << a[i].title << endl; break;
            case 'c': for (i=0; i<Max; i++) cout << a[i].bopname << endl; break;
            case 'd': for (i=0; i<Max; i++)
                        switch (a[i].preference)
                        {
                            case 0: cout << a[i].fullname << endl; break;
                            case 1: cout << a[i].title << endl; break;
                            case 2: cout << a[i].bopname << endl; break;
                        }
                      break;
        }
        cout << "Next choice: ";
        (cin >> ch).get();
    }
    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program displays a lot of rubbish as follows:

```
Benevolent Order of Programmers Report
a. display by name          b. display by title
c. display by bopname       d. display by preference
q. quit
Enter your choice: a
Steve Jobs
Bill Gates
Mark
Edward
Larry Page
^?&i?
'=YV?
K>YV?
f?YV?
??YV?
xterm-256color
11dry7st9vkb200000gn/T/
T3PDw/Render
anguage (C++)
B6
qUSg/Listeners
Message=/tmp/launch-Gpgr3C/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
ge (C++)/cpp
boris
Next choice:
```

Can anybody explain to me the reason and tell me how to correct this program? I've also tried to replace (cin >> ch).get() with just cin >> ch. It also doesn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're writing C++, then use std::string and std::vector. Once you became acquainted with STL, you will come to appreciate the advantages it offers. However, this doesn't mean you simply skip arrays. Once you really understood arrays and pointers, move on to STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your inner implementation.  You do the following:

```
case 'a': for (i=0; i<Max; i++) cout << a[i].fullname << endl; break;
//case 'b': ...
```

If you look at the top, Max is defined as 20:

```
const int Max=20;
```

But your array only has 5 members in it:

```
bop a[5]=
{
    {"Steve Jobs", "BFF", "Rita",0},
    {"Bill Gates", "BFF2", "Ann",1},
    {"Mark", "BFF3", "Boss", 2},
    {"Edward", "BFF4", "Jiezha", 2},
    {"Larry Page", "BFF5", "Michele", 1}
};
```

So when it prints the values for indices 6-19, it prints garbage.  Count the number of lines of garbage plus the number of lines of correct output.  Perfect 20.

Comment: One might specify a 'last/empty array element' specification as for such situations as e.g. `{ NULL , NULL, NULL, -1 }`

Comment: Err... I have to admit it's purely a careless error. Btw, could you tell me why replacing (cin >> ch).get() with cin >> ch has no effect at all? If I use cin >> ch; and key in one character and a newline, isn't the newline character buffered and be read in the next cin >> ch;?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're iterating beyond the bounds of your array. Why are you iterating to 20 (MAX)? It looks like you should have iterated to 5, instead.

Also, you should include in your question what your expected output was.

Comment: It's a really a careless mistake. Thanks!